# Did the pressure unit "bar" change definitions since the 1930s?

Tags: pressure, acoustics, unit

[I don't see anything in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bar_(unit)) about it, but (from [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/114132/176)) when I try to reproduce the equations in [this 1933 paper](https://asa.scitation.org/doi/abs/10.1121/1.1915608), I get values 10<sup>6</sup> away from the values in the paper.  When I reproduce this equation, for instance:

[image: The r.m.s. pressure P in the interval between f1 and f2, is ... For example, if f1=1000 and f2=6000 c.p.s., P=5×10<sup>−5</sup> bars]

I get [5×10<sup>−11</sup> bar](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(8%20%CF%80%20*%201.2754%20kg%2Fm%C2%B3%20*%201.38065*10%5E-23%20J%2FK%20*%20300%20K%2F(3*340.27%20m%2Fs)*((6000%20Hz)%5E3%20-%20(1000%20Hz)%5E3))%5E(1%2F2)%20to%20bar)

Likewise, it says:

[image: At 1000 c.p.s the average M.A.F observed is 1.9×10<sup>−16</sup> watts per cm², corresponding to a pressure 71 db below 1 bar.]

Sound intensity and pressure are related by acoustic impedance of air *Z*<sub>0</sub> = 400 N·s/m<sup>3</sup>.

So

- 1.9×10<sup>−16</sup> W/cm² ↔ [2.7×10<sup>−5</sup> Pa](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sqrt(1.9%C3%9710%5E-16+W%2Fcm%C2%B2+*+400+N%C2%B7s%2Fm%C2%B3)+to+Pa)
- 71 dB below 1 bar = 2.8×10<sup>−4</sup> ⋅ 1×10<sup>5</sup> Pa = [28 Pa](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=10%5E(-71%2F20)%20%E2%8B%85%201%20bar%20to%20Pa)

Comment: No the definition of the unit **bar** has not changed. It has always been approximately 1 atmosphere of pressure, ie 100 000 Pa

Comment: I wonder how long it will take for "bars" as a unit of mobile phone signal strength to outweigh the unit of pressure in common usage?

Comment: Or how many in the street... when going drinking :)

Comment: At STP 1 bar is 101325 pa if I remember correctly.

Comment: @SolarMike They're both units of pressure, so STP doesn't matter, and it's exactly 100,000 Pa in every definition I've found.

Comment: @endolith STP doesn't matter : at STP 1 mole of any gas occupies 22.4L... but perhaps that doesn't matter to you.

Comment: interestingly the "standard pressure" in STP actually varies by context, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_conditions_for_temperature_and_pressure, it is 101325 or 100000 Pa depending on who you ask.  In any case a `bar` is always 10^5 pa

Comment: I think 1 bar = 100,000 Pa  and 1 atm = 1.01325 bar = 101325 Pa

Comment: I suspect the answer is that the reference to “bar” actually means “barye”, which is a pressure unit in the cgs system.  According to Wikipedia, 1 bar is 1 million barye.  https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barye